# HTML fixed large element

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've been racking my brain and my Google Fu for a few hours now trying to find a solution to this one, but can't seem to come up with anything satisfactory.

I want to affix an element to the side of the page for some search criteria, much like Bootstrap's "Affix" plugin. ([Demo Here](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html)). The problem is that it's going to be very common that the element is much taller than the window. So there will be scrolling of the element itself involved.

Usually this wouldn't be a problem because as the user hits the top + bottom of the document they would be able to see the top and bottom of the fixed element. (See bootstrap example while shrinking you're window very short). But we're planning on using infinite scroll on our results set, meaning there won't be a bottom to hit, and therefore they'll never see the bottom of the fixed element. As the user scrolls down, it needs to be bottom fixed so the user sees all criteria, then on the way up, it needs to be top fixed.

So I started off by modifying Bootstrap's plugin (I'm not actually using bootstrap). Now scrolling down the page is easy, using a fixed point on the bottom of the element means that it's not affixed until you reach the bottom of it.

But scrolling back up again is where I'm hitting issues.

Am I missing something really obvious and easy here (it is Monday morning after all), or does anyone know of a plugin / patch to bootstraps affix.

**TL;DR**
Need to affix a very tall element to the page and allow it to scroll. So it's fixed on the way down, then as they scroll back up, the element isn't fixed so it's also being scrolled up. Once the top of the element is hit, fix it there.

Comment: Here's a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6rQvq/15/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you Want to do **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ijiqow/33)**

Simple jQuery function that will help.

```
$(function()
  {
 affix= $(".affix-top");
 var affixHeight = parseInt(affix.height());
 var affixTop    = parseInt(affix.offset().top);
 var affixBottom = parseInt(affixTop + affixHeight);

// Bind a scroll event for the whole page
$(document).bind("scroll", function(e) 
{
    // Calculate how far down the user has scrolled
    var screenBottom = parseInt($(window).height() +$(window).scrollTop()  );

    // Test if the div has been revealed
    if(screenBottom > affixBottom)
    {
      affix.attr("style","");
      affix.css({"bottom":"0px","position":"fixed"});
    }
   else
   {
    affix.attr("style","");
    affix.css({"top":"0px","position":"relative"});
   }
});

  });
```

Comment: Thanks, that's very close, this is about where I got to (although not nearly as elegantly). But if you scroll maybe 50% of the page, then want to get to the "Dropdowns" button on the menu, you have to scroll all the way back to the top of the page. This seems to be the sticking point I couldn't pass.

Comment: Man that's a logic flaw. you have to think an alternative of this. You can do one thing check for user scrolling direction and accordingly change the menu position from top to bottom or bottom to top.